# How to backup chrome session manager extension on linux and windows?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, windows-8.1, backup, google-chrome-extensions

I've found google chrome's profile in the file directory's of both linux and windows, but I can't find session manager amongst the extensions (and have my doubts that loading up the profile will work as intended).

Comment: YOU CAN NOT  "save" the Session manager  its the **singleton cookie stuff** but IT will auto re-sync on transport if  copied  (will get a warning at least on  linux  that  it had 'Operation Not allowed"

Comment: So  syncing the profile and downloading the extension will cut it?

Comment: sudo cp -r ~/.config/google/*  /usb  (or wherever )  and the reverse later yes

Comment: I grok you now on the singleton cookie thing, but you're saying i should use the sudo command when I'm copying it to a new system?  I'm trying sudo cp -r~/home/user/.config/google-chrome/ and the command is invalid.

Comment: there is a <space>   in between cp -r  <space>  ~/username/.config     for ex.  sudo cp -r  ~/linux-modder/.config/google-chrome  the   sudo part is mainly for  usbs and such if YOU own the destination file  it is not needed..   for ex  copying from    ~/.config/google-chrome to  say ~/Documents

Comment: Copying and pasting it into my USB also works, right? And from there, if I add the cookie to my chrome profile on a new computer, it will recover my session manager sessions right?

Comment: Yes to a usb or  even  NFS (shared / networked drive works)  will edit my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Session Manager in chrome is keep in the `Singleton Cookie`  which is in `~/.config/google-chrome/...`.   Of note (especially if a open session  (foreground OR background) is active,   You will get a `Operation Not Permitted`  this is primarily  because the `Token `` is more or less hashed to that session and machine the configs from it however transfer.

To backup or migrate your full settings all that is needed is to:

**Linux**:

cp -r ~/.config/google-chrome/*  /${some mountpoint} ## for ex. a  usb mountpoint or somewhere else you need /desire it for backup / version control

ex.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb  /media
sudo cp -r ~/.config/google-chrome/* /media
```

**MAC**:

cp -r ~USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Preferences/{some mountpoint}

ex.

```
 sudo mount /dev/disk1   /Volumes/$USERNAME/foo
 sudo cp -r ~USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Preferences  /Volumes/$USERNAME/foo
```

**Windows**:

cp -r C:\Documents and Settings*UserName*\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default /{some mountpoint}

ex.

SELECT DISK  1

XCOPY /E C:\Documents and Settings*UserName*\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default   /DISK1/foo

Comment: I've done this , and everything but the singleton stuff has been sent. When I try to send that over it says file manager does not support symbolic links.

Comment: that is fine they are recreated on new instance be that a reisntall or  new hdd/sdd